# ogr2ogr Export spatial data from SQL Server to Spatialite

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr, spatialite

I am trying to export some spatial data from SQL Server 2012 to Spatialite with the following command

```
ogr2ogr  -f SQLite -update C:\tmp\Spatial.sqlite -nln "my_polygons" "MSSQL:server=host;database=MySQLDB;trusted_connection=yes;GeometryFormat=native;" -sql "SELECT *  FROM MySQLDB.dbo.my_polygons"  -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=yes -gt 65536
```

Ogr2ogr does write from SQL Server to my Spatialite db however the imported table is not recognised as a spatial table.

When trying to view the result in QGIS is doesn't show any polygons. However I can see the table and the attributes!

[image: Spatial data from SQL Server not recognised in Spatialite]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has the same issue, here is the workaround.

I found out that the geometry_type and srid weren't blank in the spatialite geometry_column.

After updating the table I got the layer coming up nicely in QGIS.